# Delete end of element from a list if the element ends with an element from another list

Tags: python, list, ends-with

I have the following two lists. If my_list **ends** with an extension from extensions, then it should be removed. I can't seem to find a solution that doesn't require too many lines of code.

Input:

```
my_list = ['abc_sum_def_sum', 'abc_sum_def_mean', 'abc_sum', 'abc_abc']

extensions = ['_sum', '_mean']
```

Output:

```
new_list = ['abc_sum_def', 'abc_sum_def', 'abc', 'abc_abc']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**One-liner list comprehension:**

```
new_list = [min(e[:(-len(ext) if e.endswith(ext) else len(e))] for ext in extensions) for e in my_list]
```

**Result:**

`['abc_sum_def', 'abc_sum_def', 'abc', 'abc_abc']`

**Explanation:**

What this does is basically loops over `my_list`, checks if its element `e` has either of the two `extensions` items at its end. If it does, it trims that extensions piece down. If it doesn't, leaves that element of `my_list` untouched. It basically first does this (without the `min` applied):

```
[[e[:(-len(ext) if e.endswith(ext) else len(e))] for ext in extensions] for e in my_list]
```

which produces:

```
[['abc_sum_def', 'abc_sum_def_sum'],
 ['abc_sum_def_mean', 'abc_sum_def'],
 ['abc', 'abc_sum'],
 ['abc_abc', 'abc_abc']]
```

and then applies `min` to collect the smaller item of each pair. That `min` corresponds to either the trimmed-down version of each element, or the untouched element itself.

Comment: Excellent! And then i suppose the min function will pick the shortest one tested, which will always amount to either the pruned one or the one without an extension?

Comment: @Mikkel Exactly! I'll make an edit in a second to further elaborate on that.

Answer (score 2):

To have a better pythonic approach, You can convert it into a list comprehension:

```
my_list = ['abc_sum_def_sum','abc_sum_def_mean','abc_sum','abc_abc']

extensions = ['_sum','_mean']
new_list =[]
for x in my_list:
    for elem in extensions:
        if x.endswith(elem):
            y = x[:-len(elem)]
            new_list.append(y)
```

Comment: I believe this doesn't quite accomplish the goal, since it produces only a part of the desired output, ie `['abc_sum_def', 'abc_sum_def', 'abc']`

Comment: This looks a lot like my own implementation - but FatihAkici is right, it doesnt entirely do the trick as it doesnt include abc_abc.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

my_list = ['abc_sum_def_sum','abc_sum_def_mean','abc_sum','abc_abc']
extensions = ['_sum','_mean']

pattern = re.compile(r"(" + "|".join(extensions) + r")$")
print([pattern.sub("", i) for i in my_list])
```

**Output:**

```
['abc_sum_def', 'abc_sum_def', 'abc', 'abc_abc']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = ['abc_sum_def_sum','abc_sum_def_mean','abc_sum','abc_abc']

extensions = ['_sum','_mean']
new_list =[]
for x in my_list:
    if x.endswith(extensions[0]) or x.endswith(extensions[1]):
        if x.endswith(extensions[0]):
            y = x[:-len(extensions[0])]
            new_list.append(y)
        else:
            y = x[:-len(extensions[1])]
            new_list.append(y)
    else:
        new_list.append(x)


print(new_list)
```

output:

```
['abc_sum_def', 'abc_sum_def', 'abc', 'abc_abc']
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using lambdas:

```
my_list = ['abc_sum_def_sum','abc_sum_def_mean','abc_sum','abc_abc']
extensions = ['_sum','_mean']

def ext_cleaner(extensions, str_arg):
    ext_found = [ext for ext in extensions if str_arg.endswith(ext)]
    ret = str_arg[:-len(ext_found[0])] if ext_found else str_arg
    return ret

list(map(lambda x: ext_cleaner(extensions, x), my_list))
```